# Plist and Mobile Provisioning File Encryption

Tags: ios, mobile, encryption, plist, obfuscation

I'm a mobile developer and currently I'm developing an ios app using ionic and angular. Right now I need to obfuscate/encrypt the plist and mobile provisioning files. Is that possible? I don't want anyone to reverse engineer my app and see or use those files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First evaluate the level of security you need.

Obfuscating is very weak but might meet your needs.

Standard file used by Apple such as Info.plist can not be encrypted by the developer. Any plist files you create can be encrypted.

Easiest and secure solution for encryption data is to use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).

But note that the encryption key will be the weak point and embedding it in the app is not very secure. That said this is about the best you can do protecting an app's data from a user on their device.

Also note that you will have to apply to the U.S. government for an exception, no real problem, just an extra hassle.

Comment: Is that possible to encrypt .plist and mobile provisioning? Is that still work properly?

Comment: Standard file used by Apple can not be encrypted by the developer. Any plist files you create can be encrypted. But why do you see a need to hide the contents of the mobile provisioning and the app plist file?

Comment: It's that my app has been through VAPT testing and their recommendation is to obfuscate/encrypt the plist and mobile provisioning file.

Comment: If the testers you are using think the Info.plist file can be obfuscated/encrypted you need to get another tester, one who has knowledge of iOS. It is unclear what "mobile provisioning file" refers to but if it is the iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile the tester is uninformed.